# Set "secure" flag on session cookie in RoR even over HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, session-cookies

In a Rails app, the session cookie can be easily set to include the `secure` cookie attribute, when sending over HTTPS to ensure that the cookie is not leaked over a non-HTTP connection.

However, if the Rails app is NOT using HTTPS, but HTTP only, it seems that it doesnt even set the cookie at all.
While this does make some sense, in this scenario there is a seperate front end load balancer, which is responsible for terminating the SSL connection. From the LB to the Rails app, the connection is HTTP only.

How can I force the Rails app to set a `secure` cookie, even when not using HTTPS?

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, if I set a cookie via `cookies[:somekey] = {value: 'somevalue', secure: true}`, then the cookie is not set in the response from Rails over HTTP?

Comment: @SebastianGoodman good question - but haven't actually tested that, I'm talking about the automatic session cookie, so it's not actually being set explicitly in code. Perhaps that might be a workaround, if it works...

Comment: So when you say "the session cookie can be easily set to include the secure cookie attribute", how are you doing in code exactly?

Comment: Same problem here. Something in Rails blocking secure cookie when we want to send them over http (because we have https converter later on)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Secure cookies are not sent over non-secure connections by definition.

Terminating SSL upstream is quite common, but you need to pass certain header fields through so that Rails knows and can do the right thing.

[Here's a document](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-setup-nginx-ssl-proxy/) that explains the configuration in pretty good detail for nginx. Search for "Set headers" to jump to the section describing the specific headers you need to pass through.

There are security considerations using this configuration, e.g., if the device terminating SSL is not on the same secure LAN as the Rails host, then you have a vulnerability.

Comment: Excellent, thats what I was hoping to find. Interesting that this is a solution at the nginx, not at the Rails... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link - adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` to nginx config worked great!

Comment: We still need a solution how to force Rails not to block secure-http cookies

Comment: not blocking secure-http cookies is not possible because by definition of 'secure' these cookies must not be sent by http (only https), Thats basicly what "secure" means.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me, and I solved it this way:
In session_store.rb I configured:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cache_store, key: COOKIE_NAME, :expire_after => 1.days, :expires_in => 1.days, :domain => 'mydomain.com', same_site: :none
```

(note that I didn't put the `, same_site: :none` here, because it would kill the set cookie completely when serving HTTP)

And then I monkey patched the Rack->Utils->set_cookie_header, by placing this file in the `initializers` folder

```
require 'rack/utils'
module Rack
  module Utils
    def self.set_cookie_header!(header, key, value)
      case value
      when Hash
        domain  = "; domain="  + value[:domain] if value[:domain]
        path    = "; path="    + value[:path]   if value[:path]
        max_age = "; max-age=" + value[:max_age] if value[:max_age]
        expires = "; expires=" +
            rfc2822(value[:expires].clone.gmtime) if value[:expires]

        # Make secure always, even in HTTP
        # secure = "; secure"  if value[:secure]
        secure = "; secure"

        httponly = "; HttpOnly" if value[:httponly]
        same_site =
            case value[:same_site]
            when false, nil
              nil
            when :none, 'None', :None
              '; SameSite=None'
            when :lax, 'Lax', :Lax
              '; SameSite=Lax'
            when true, :strict, 'Strict', :Strict
              '; SameSite=Strict'
            else
              raise ArgumentError, "Invalid SameSite value: #{value[:same_site].inspect}"
            end
        value = value[:value]
      end
      value = [value] unless Array === value
      cookie = escape(key) + "=" +
          value.map { |v| escape v }.join("&") +
          "#{domain}#{path}#{max_age}#{expires}#{secure}#{httponly}#{same_site}"

      case header["Set-Cookie"]
      when nil, ''
        header["Set-Cookie"] = cookie
      when String
        header["Set-Cookie"] = [header["Set-Cookie"], cookie].join("\n")
      when Array
        header["Set-Cookie"] = (header["Set-Cookie"] + [cookie]).join("\n")
      end

      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The base issue is, that by definition of [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), cookies with secure set may only be sent via secure connetions.
So not sending cookies with secure set over HTTP is the expected behavior.

You might want to set different cookie options in different environments.
In config/environments/developent.rb you clould set

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.session_store :cache_store, key: COOKIE_NAME, same_site: :none
end
```

and in production (config/environments/production.rb), where you deploy your site with HTTPS:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.session_store :cache_store, key: COOKIE_NAME, same_site: :lax, secure: true
end
```