# How to force a secure cookie over HTTP with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ssl, cookies, nginx

I'm working with a Rails app that sits behind a reverse-proxy server (Nginx), and I need the session cookie for the Rails app to be flagged `Secure`. However, when I set it like below,

`Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_app_session', :secure => true`

Rails stops sending the `_app_session` cookie.

I know Rails is holding it back because I am hitting Rails directly with `curl -v`, and I can see the `_app_session` cookie when I omit `:secure => true`.

**How do I force Rails to send the secure cookie over the HTTP connection?**

**Note:** It's okay, in this specific scenario, to be sending a secure cookie over HTTP. This traffic is happening in an area considered secure before getting wrapped in SSL and sent out into the world. Further, "[terminating SSL upstream is quite common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15003911/538222)", so I'm not the first to have a setup like this.

#### Alternatives (What Doesn't Work)

Here's what I've tried already:

I wrote a script in Lua that adds `Secure` to the cookie. It worked, but my boss said we can't have Lua in the Nginx.

I couldn't figure out how to use the following directives in Nginx to achieve what I wanted:

- $http_header
- proxy_set_header
- more_set_headers
- $cookie_COOKIE

I tried adding `set_proxy_header` and `add_header` as suggested [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-setup-nginx-ssl-proxy/), but it didn't work, and I suspect there's something peculiar about our setup that may be causing that.

Finally, hypothetically I could write a C module for Nginx, but I'm not going to do that.

Answer (score 6):

I added the following to the relevant `location` blocks in my Nginx conf file:

`proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;`

It didn't work before because I had used `X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme` at the suggestion of the link in my question. I don't know why that didn't work, but doing

`$ curl -v -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" http://localhost:95/app-path`

does return the expected `_app_session` cookie, with the `Secure` flag set, so clearly RoR just needs to know that the secure cookie will end up going out over https.

**Update (Jun 2015)**

The reason why I had trouble with this was because our servers were proxy passing `http` requests to themselves for `https` and not setting `X-Forwarded-Proto` first. Once I understood our topology better, I was able to do `X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme` before the first proxy pass. That is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the rack-ssl-enforcer gem. Removes the problem from rails and it's highly configurable to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is always secure, the best way is to add `proxy_cookie_flags` (since Nginx version 1.19.3) configuration to your Nginx (in your desired `location`). There is no need for an additional script.

For all cookies use:

`proxy_cookie_flags ~ secure;`

Check more in the documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_flags